# Can't read mp4 files in opencv 3

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I can't get opencv 3.0.0 (the pre-compiled version from the opencv website) to even compile when trying to open files using VideoCapture.

I pared my code down to just this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <time.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main() {
   VideoCapture inputCap("C:/Users/user.name/Desktop/Video0022.mp4");
}
```

And compiling it yields: `opencv_ffmpeg300_64.dll : fata error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x408`, in the file opencv_ffmpeg300_64.dll, line 1, col 1.

This is using Visual Studio Express 2012, on a Win 7 machine, compiling in x64, in C++. I've tried compiling the code in Release mode, and Debug mode, and it gives the same error. The dll is in the linker additional dependencies, and I have the library it's in in the additional library directories.

That didn't work, and looking around I saw that in the Java and Python versions, adding the directory to the path variable sometimes worked. So did that, rebooted, tried again, same error.

Then I just started adding the dll everywhere it could possibly be useful - all through the My Documents/Visual Studio 12/Projects/ProjectName folder, in multiple places in the opencv folder, and still the same error.

I also tried turning off the enabling incremental linking, and that didn't work either.

I'm pretty sure it's not a codec problem, as this was working in opencv 2.4.7/visual studio 10 (I renamed the folder opencv 2 folder to not mess with the opencv 3.0.0 install).

The video itself is fine, I'm able to open it in VLC and windows media player no problem, and with the older opencv stuff.

If I remove the dll from the linker additional dependencies, I can actually compile the .cpp, but then it never actually opens the file (`inputCap.isOpened()` always returns false). However, I can open webcams with no problem.

--

Edit: I changed the release runtime library to /MT instead of /MD, removed the opencv_ffmpeg300_64.dll on both the debug and the release versions of the linker additional dependencies and now both the release and the debug compile and work fine for that video file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Didn't realize the ettiquite was to answer with a question if I solved my own problem, whoops)

Managed to fix it by changing the release runtime library to /MT instead of /MD, removed the opencv_ffmpeg300_64.dll on both the debug and the release versions of the linker additional dependencies and now both the release and the debug compile and work fine for that video file.